# Using Oracle SQL to join duplicate counts to an existing subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have been asked to build a query that runs quality checks for data on a certain state test.

I have the following query that creates a variable named 'Flag' to identify cases where there are issues. The main query is really in a subquery, and I filter out all records where there isn't a flag by only selecting cases where Flag has a value.

I would like to be able to have a CASE WHEN for instances where there are duplicate tests. We do have some duplicates where, for the same student ID (test.studentID, studenttestscore.studentID, students.ID), a student will have the same test date for the same exam.

Test date, as you can see, is STUDENTTEST.TEST_DATE. Exams can be identified by either STUDENTTEST.ID or TEST.NAME. It might be easier to look for records where STUDENTTEST.test_date and STUDENTTEST.ID are the same for a STUDENTTEST.studentID. But once you get that count, it would have to be appended to the subquery here so that we can have a student name associated with it.

```
with query as (select STUDENTS.STUDENT_NUMBER as "Student ID", Students.Lastfirst as "Student Name",
    STUDENTS.GRADE_LEVEL as "Current Grade Level",
    TEST.NAME as "Test Name",
    STUDENTTEST.GRADE_LEVEL as "Grade level at time of exam",
    STUDENTTEST.TEST_DATE as TEST_DATE,
    STUDENTTESTSCORE.NUMSCORE as Score, STUDENTTESTSCORE.PERCENTSCORE as PCTScore,
S_NY_STU_X.DATEOFENTRYGRade9 as Cohort,
CASE
WHEN STUDENTTEST.GRADE_LEVEL <9 or STUDENTTEST.GRADE_LEVEL>12 then 'Invalid Grade Level'
WHEN STUDENTTESTSCORE.NUMSCORE != STUDENTTESTSCORE.PERCENTSCORE then 'Mismatch between number and percent score'
WHEN TEST.NAME like '% - T%' then 'Transitional Global no longer administered'
WHEN STUDENTTEST.TEST_DATE>CURRENT_DATE THEN 'Test date invalid'
WHEN STUDENTTESTSCORE.NUMSCORE <0 THEN 'Test score out of range'
WHEN STUDENTTESTSCORE.NUMSCORE <0 THEN 'Test score out of range'
WHEN STUDENTTESTSCORE.NUMSCORE >100  THEN 'Test score out of range'
WHEN STUDENTTESTSCORE.PERCENTSCORE > 100 THEN 'Test score out of range'
END AS Flag
 from STUDENTS STUDENTS,
    STUDENTTEST STUDENTTEST,
    STUDENTTESTSCORE STUDENTTESTSCORE,
    TEST TEST,
    TESTSCORE TESTSCORE,
    S_NY_STU_X S_NY_STU_X

 where 
 Test.Name like 'Regents%' and
 STUDENTTESTSCORE.TESTSCOREID=TESTSCORE.ID
    and STUDENTTESTSCORE.STUDENTTESTID=STUDENTTEST.ID
    and STUDENTTESTSCORE.STUDENTID=STUDENTTEST.STUDENTID
    and STUDENTS.ID=STUDENTTEST.STUDENTID
    and STUDENTS.ID=STUDENTTESTSCORE.STUDENTID
    and STUDENTTEST.TESTID=TEST.ID
and S_NY_STU_X.STUDENTSDCID=STUDENTS.DCID)
select * from query where flag is not null
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood you can add this analytical `count()` to your `case`:

```
when count(1) over (partition by studenttest.test_date, 
                                 studenttest.id, 
                                 studenttest.studentid) > 1 
then 'duplicate'
```

Here is the example:

```
with t (test_date, test_id, student_id) as (
    select date '2013-05-18', 707, 20214 from dual union all
    select date '2013-05-18', 707, 20214 from dual union all
    select date '2013-05-12', 707, 20214 from dual union all
    select date '2023-05-18', 707,  1003 from dual union all
    select date '2013-05-02', 705,  1003 from dual )
select t.*, 
       case 
            when test_date > current_date 
            then 'Test date invalid'
            when count(1) over (partition by test_date, test_id, student_id) > 1 
            then 'duplicated test' 
       end as flag
  from t
```

Result:

```
TEST_DATE      TEST_ID STUDENT_ID FLAG
----------- ---------- ---------- -----------------
2013-05-02         705       1003 
2013-05-12         707      20214 
2013-05-18         707      20214 duplicated test
2013-05-18         707      20214 duplicated test
2023-05-18         707       1003 Test date invalid
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks so much:)